# redirect URI mismatch error for google auth 2.0 and openid connect (OAuth Client ID type "Chrome Extension" and "Web Application")

Tags: google-chrome-extension, oauth-2.0, google-oauth, google-openid, sign-in-with-google

I'm very new to chrome extension development. I'm trying to integrate google authentication to a chrome extension that I'm building. First, I added google auth using a OAuth client ID of type "Chrome Extension" that doesn't require you to enter your redirect URI when setting up. When trying to sign in with the extension, I get the pop-up for google login with the following error:

> You can’t sign in because this app sent an invalid request. You can
> try again later or contact the developer about this issue.
>
> If you are a developer of this app, see error details.
>
> Error 400: redirect_uri_mismatch

I've checked hundreds of times and found that the redirect URI is correct. I've checked the extension ID and found it the same. I'm using the code `chrome.identity.getRedirectURL()` to get the redirect URI and it returns the correct URI. I've tried passing the redirect URI to the web auth flow encoded as well but no luck and the error is persistent.

To try a different approach, I've created an OAuth Client ID of type "Web Application" which explicitly requires you to enter the redirect URI at the time of creation. But the error is the same and persistent.

I'm not sure at this point what else I can try. I'd appreciate any help regarding this. Also, I'm not sure what other information I can provide but let me know what other information you'd need. I have mostly used [this](https://anobjectisa.com/?p=34) tutorial to implement oauth using "Web Application" method.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

Follow this [guide](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/mv3/tut_oauth/) instead to integrate Google Identity services into your Chrome extension. The [`launchWebAuthFlow()` method](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/identity/#method-launchWebAuthFlow) enables auth flows for non-Google identity providers. You should be using the [`getAuthToken()` method](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/identity/#method-getAuthToken) instead which delivers the OAuth 2.0 response directly to your app and doesnt require you to provide a redirect URI.

Comment: this guide creates "chrome app" type client ID which is not supported and not one of the options anymore. I tried following the document using "chrome extension" instead but at the stage where I'm supposed to see an OAuth token in the console window, I get an error instead "Unchecked runtime.lastError: OAuth2 request failed: Service responded with error: 'bad request'". I'm assuming it's because this guide isn't correct anymore since it's for "chrome app".

Comment: You created the correct Client ID type, the guide just needs to be updated. You got the "bad request" error message likely because you didnt update the scope list in your manifest file, add https://www.googleapis.com/auth/contacts.readonly to the scopes array.  Note that `getAuthToken()` returns an access token and wouldnt return an ID token. If you are implementing this solely for authN via Sign in with Google, you can use the `launchWebAuthFlow()` method; I verified that actually still works. A common cause for the `redirect_uri_mismatch` error is when you have / in one but not the other.